# PHPSESSID behavour not possible on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, session, ubuntu

Does anyone know if Ubuntu have permanently killed or broken support for session.use_trans_sid?

I'm working on a project that requires the PHPSESSID appended to each URL (can't change this, unfortunately).

For some reason, I can't get this working on Ubuntu (Ubuntu 10.10, PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5). However, it does work on CentOS (CentOS 5.6 , PHP 5.3.6).

Here is the test code:

```
phpinfo();
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', true);
ini_set('session.use_cookies', false);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', false);
ini_set('arg_separator.output','&amp;');
ini_set("url_rewriter.tags","a=href,area=href,frame=src");
session_start();
echo '<a href="/foo">test<?a>';
exit;
```

On CentOS, the link is correctly output with PHPSESSID on the end, but not Ubuntu. I'd rather not port my whole development environment for this project over if I can avoid it. ;)

Comment: Have you tried changing it in php.ini or setting it in .htaccess instead of using ini_set?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, but yes tried changing it in php.ini. These are all run-time configurations, but best to be sure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to work in Ubuntu 11 (Ubuntu 11.04, PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2). Test page here: http://test.nik.mt-dev.co.uk/sessiontest.php